# Top navigation on subsite inheritance from parent site declaratively

Tags: 2013

Is it possible via onet.xml to create the top navigation bar based on the top navigation from site collection?

Only line I see in my onet about the top navigation is this

```
 <NavBar Name="$Resources:core,category_Top;" Separator="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;" Body="&lt;a ID='onettopnavbar#LABEL_ID#' href='#URL#' accesskey='J'&gt;#LABEL#&lt;/a&gt;" ID="1002" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT WITH CORRECT ANSWER: I found the correct answer this time. You'll want to make sure the following is in your `WebFeatures` section:

```
<WebFeatures>
    <Feature ID="541F5F57-C847-4e16-B59A-B31E90E6F9EA">
        <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
            <Property Key="InheritGlobalNavigation" Value="true"/>
            <Property Key="ShowSiblings" Value="true"/>
            <Property Key="IncludeSubSites" Value="true"/>
        </Properties>
    </Feature>
</WebFeatures>
```

The operative element being `<Property Key="InheritGlobalNavigation" Value="true"/>`. The other properties you can set to true/false as they apply to your situation.